# Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems and Vulcan Logic: how do they cope with it?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

According to Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems, it is not possible to find an answer to any question using a formal system based on axioms.

The theorems state that:

> **First Incompleteness Theorem**: Any consistent formal system F within which a certain amount of elementary arithmetic can be carried out is incomplete; i.e., there are statements of the language of F which can neither be proved nor disproved in F.
>
> **Second Incompleteness Theorem**: Assume F is a consistent formalized system which contains elementary arithmetic. Then *F ⊬ Cons(F)*.
>
> -- From the Wikipedia article on [Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems)

Basically, what it means is that there are either questions you cannot answer and if you can answer all questions, you'll have contraditions (i.e., can prove that one thing is true and false at the same time).

Has it ever been stated (canon or EU) how the Vulcans cope with this problem? There being answers they cannot find using logic alone (which is a formal system)? So, assuming that Vulcans also have found this theorems (and as it was published in 1931, it is quite feasible to assume that Vulcans having been more advanced than humans for a long time also know about this), how does it reflect in their philosophy to not be able to find answers using only logic and has it any effect on their daily lifes?

Comment: or..."Vulcans having been more advanced than humans for a long time also know about this"...and have proven it incorrect and have a more advanced logic ;)

Comment: "Logic, logic....  Logic is the beginning of wisdom, Valeris, not the end."

Comment: How are Vulcans able to cope with the fact that there are mathematical theorems they aren't able to prove? That's a tough one. The same way everyone else does?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Using logic doesn't need to rely on consistency of the axioms of arithmetic.**

The incompleteness theorems of Gödel, even as you've stated them in your question, are about formal logic systems containing *elementary arithmetic*. They are not a way of saying "logic doesn't work"; they are simply a statement about the unsolvability of certain queries in the extremely abstract branch of pure mathematics.

Normal life can go on quite comfortably without worrying about the consistency of the axioms of arithmetic. Even research in mathematics, which relies entirely on logical deduction and ultimately somewhat on elementary arithmetic, can continue in a natural way without worrying about Gödel's incompleteness theorems. *[Source: I am a mathematician.]*

Gödel's incompleteness theorems do not make logic useless or unworkable. They do not even make logic relying on arithmetic useless or unworkable. You and I make decisions every day based on logic, and we are perfectly able to do so despite the issues lying at the root of abstract arithmetic systems. Vulcans would also be perfectly able to operate on logic in their everyday lives, without worrying about such issues.

You're massively overestimating the relevance of Gödel's incompleteness theorems to ... basically anyone outside of esoteric mathematical logic theory.

Comment: I think that should be "able to express at least statements about elementary arithmetic over inetgers" . Any formal system that can express more is affected by the same problems.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they need to cope with this.

Vulcans are not supposed to be a mathematical logic system; in fact they cannot because [their head would explode due to sheer computational load](http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~cherniak/CACM_88.pdf) [PDF] (ok, this *is* Star Trek).

We know from AI that useful systems (i.e. those that emit answers in adequate time) **that are based on some logic** (of which there are many) need to confine themselves to tractable formalisms and proof methods. In fact, they often are:

1. Restricted to simple theorems/axioms, namely [Horn Clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause)
2. Restricted to simple & fast proof procedures, generally [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic))
3. Radically incomplete: many statements, though true, remain unprovable in such systems both for practical and theoretical reasons.
4. Only have a limited ability to express "real world statements" and translation of utterances into a formal language is fraught with ambiguity and loss of meaning. There may not even proper negation to express that something "is not true".
5. Absolutely must be able to handle inconsistent & uncertain knowledge if they want to deal with the real world (see also: [Paraconsistent Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-paraconsistent/)). Classical Logic, where every statement must take on exactly one truth value (either True or False) is just not sufficient (but it *is* sufficient for text processing, compilers, closed-world theorem proving etc). In fact, depending on their purpose, those systems must be able to handle a probability calculus (and doing that is expensive in computational operations, too).

See also: [Automated Reasoning](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reasoning-automated/) for an excellent review of the above.

But back to Vulcans: "Applying Logic" would really just mean: Apply slow and precise reasoning (best on large sheets of paper) to arrive at arguably correct and reviewable solutions. Avoid error-prone shortcuts and fallacies of [fast and approximate reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristics_in_judgment_and_decision-making) (this includes Twitter shrieks and Tricorder beeps). That's already a tall order. Vulcans might well be mostly bogged down accumulating data and processing it again and again, reviewing the changing conclusions, unable to make a timely decision, like people affected by neurosis (or like the Mars shuttle control system in Stanislaw Lem's *Ananke*.)

Answer (score -3):

An Axiom is taken to be true, not proven to be true. 
Logic is the study of of the validity of phenomena and interactions based on it's observed characteristics and behaviors.

Comment: Logic consists of more than just axioms.  How does this address Vulcans' relationship with the Incompleteness Theorems?